# Relational database design - multiple group assignments

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I'm trying to work out the best design for a database system. The problem is how to best create the tables for a relation that works out.
One person can be a member of different organizations. Each organization is in it's own table because that organization belongs to a group of organizations. I cannot merge the tables of the different groups of organizations.

I want to know which organizations the person is a member of and several other details pertaining to having been assigned to that organization.
A person can be assigned to an organization and later end his membership with the organization. Each assignment should have a date. Later he could be assigned to the organization once more. I want to keep track of all the assignments.

The problem is that I can't put all organizations in one table. They are in different tables because they have different attributes and some of the tables are not really under my control.

Some example tables (simplified):

```
TABLE people (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name VARCHAR(50),
    last_name VARCHAR(50)
)

TABLE group_assignments (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY
    person_id INT,
    organiation_id INT, -- This is the problem. How to create the proper relation.
    assignment_date DATETIME,
    assignment_end_date DATETIME
)

-- First group of organizations
TABLE airports (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    airport_name VARCHAR(50)
)

-- Second group of organizations
TABLE restaurants (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    restaurant_name VARCHAR(50)
)

-- Third group of organizations
TABLE schools (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    school_name VARCHAR(50)
)
```

Now let's say a person is assigned to:
    `[airports]` id 3
    `[restaurants]` id 5

And another person is assigned to:
    `[restaurants]` id 4
    `[schools]` id 7

How should I define a table that could define these relations properly?

Comment: FWIW, I've generally found it best to create `people_airports`, `people_restaurants`, `people_bocceleagues`, ... with a `person_id` and `bocceleague_id` (or whatever) in each. If there are additional _business rules_, e.g. pilots must be licensed or you can't join multiple leagues, they can be implemented with constraints or triggers on the tables. You can always create a view that merges all of the data and includes an `organization_type` column. (As a rule, it is easier to merge differing things as needed than to pry apart things that were tossed together for "convenience".)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I think the "shared primary key" approach might be the best approach.

Create a table organizations:

```
create table Organizations (
    OrganizationId int identity primary key,
    . . .
);
```

Then create the subtables:

```
create table airports (
    AirportId INT PRIMARY KEY,
    airport_name VARCHAR(50),
    constraint fk_airports_airportid
        foreign key (AirportId) references Organizations(OrganizationId)
);
```

Then you can have the foreign key relationship in `group_assignments` to `Organizations`.  In fact, I would just call that table `PersonOrganizations`.

This particular method maintains most of the relational integrity.  It does not guarantee that one "organization" in not in multiple subtables.  This is also possible to enforce.

You can do so with subtypes.  This would look like:

```
create table Organizations (
    OrganizationId int identity primary key,
    OrganizationType varchar(255) not null
    . . .,
    constraint unq_OrganizationId_OrganizationType unique (OrganizationId, OrganizationType)  -- needed for foreign key reference validating type
);

create table airports (
    AirportId INT PRIMARY KEY,
    airport_name VARCHAR(50),
    OrganizationType as ('airport')
    constraint fk_airports_airportid
        foreign key (AirportId, OrganizationType) references Organizations(OrganizationId, OrganizationType),
);
```

Comment: Thank you that makes sense. The only problem is that I can't change the primary keys of the sub tables because they're already used in other relations.

Comment: @MortenTwellmann . . . Nothing in this answer changes the primary keys of the subs tables.

Comment: If I have two tables, e.g. airports and schools. Then each of them would have id 1, 2, 3, 4. With the foreign key constraint referencing the organizations table it would create a conflict as I the id's would be the table. Or maybe there is something I didn't understand?

Comment: @MortenTwellmann . . . Yes.  The keys in the "sub" tables are not identities.  When you insert a row in `airports`, you need to also insert a row in `organizations` and then use that id as the id for `airports`.  (You can have separate ids, but it seems unnecessary.)